# Accounting: Equipment Debt Schedule and bank Draw

Tags: accounting

If a company is paying off an equipment debt schedule with more $ than they owe on the balance sheet . What happens with the accounting entry ?

For Example: Cash: DR 400 (a) Cr 400 (c)

Debt Schedule: DR:300 (B) CR:300 (c)

Debt/Bank: 400 (a)

A. Draw from Bank on equipment line for $400

B. Balance sheet value of $300

C. C. Debt schedule payoff $400 . What happens to the $100

Answer (score 0):

When you use the money form the line credit to purchase the equipment it will be recorded as either

```
Dr. Cash  XXXX.XX

    Cr. LOC                XXXX.XX

Dr. Equipment XXXX.XX

  Cr. Cash               XXXX.XX
```

or if paid directly to the vendor from the LOC

```
Dr. Equipment XXXX.XX

  Cr. LOC                XXXX.XX
```

When you pay off the LOC any additional amount paid would go to interest expense.

```
Dr.LOC           XXXX.XX

Dr.Interest Exp    XX.XX

  Cr.Cash                    XXXX.XX

  Cr.Cash                      XX.XX
```